# Парсинг json на кириллице

Tags: json, ios, objective-c, парсер

Не могу понять, как распарсить json на русском языке? Чтобы на uilabel выводился русский текст.

Мой код:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     NSString *str = @"{" "\"Город\":[\"Москва\"]" "}";

     NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

     NSLog(@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"Город"]);

    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];  
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
NSLog: 2017-09-05 12:43:50.840 SMJson[1919:81023] ("\U041c\U043e\U0441\U043a\U0432\U0430")
```

А на `uilabel` выводится `nill`

Comment: тебе нужно декодировать строку. Гугли objective-c decode string

Comment: да уже облазил весь интернет, не могу найти.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"%@", (NSString*)dict[@"Город"][0]);
self.label.text = (NSString*)dict[@"Город"][0];
```

NSLog(@"%@", dict[@"Город"][0]); -> Mocква

У вас же массив, выведите первый элемент

2017-09-05 18:31:03.446 test[94631:8285509] Москва

ну или уберите [ и ] в JSON

Comment: спасибо, получилось!

Answer (score 0):

На русском языке довольно легко парсить JSON используя Swift 4, **protocol Decodable**.

Код такой:

```
import Foundation

let json = """
{
    "Город" : ["Москва"]
}
"""

struct Место : Decodable {
    let Город : [String]
}

func __test_so_714559() {
    print("[TEST]: \(#function)")
    let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let места = try! decoder.decode(Место.self, from:data!)
    print(места.Город[0])
    print("[/TEST]")
}
```

Результат:

```
[TEST]: __test_so_714559()
Москва
[/TEST]
```